# Why do I receive the 'Unlock Focus used too many times' message?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using a menu driven application to access various class nibs and receive the above error message on the first selection.  I receive this message the first time only.  While not an application killing message, I am trying to resolve the warning.

To note there are 5 various classes I access

I access various class nibs via buttons in the code of my appDelegate.m thru code like the following:

```
- (IBAction)btnShowPriceSource:(id)sender {
    if (ps == nil){

        ps = [[PriceSource alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PriceSource"];

    }

    [ps showWindow:nil];
}
```

The message I receive is as follows:

```
2015-01-05 12:13:08.671 Stamp Collection[2527:442573] unlockFocus called too many times. Called on <NSButton: 0x608000140420>.
```

How do I eliminate this message?

Comment: What OS X version? Are you using layer-backed views? I have seen this a lot, and some bizarre crashes under 10.10 (same code ran fine on 10.9).

Comment: Interesting - I have gone to 10.10.1 and have noticed then.  I do not remember having this issue under 10.9.

Answer (score 2):

This message is telling you that a `-lockFocus` is unbalanced with its `-unlockFocus`. This can be as part of an `NSView` or `NSImage`. There are many reasons this might happen. You might be calling `lockFocus` somewhere directly, and failing to unlock. You might be drawing into a `NSGraphicsContext` or image without first calling `lockFocus`. You might be performing drawing on a background thread.

If you can reproduce it fairly reliably, you may want to put a symbolic breakpoint on `-[UIView unlockFocus]` and `-[NSImage unlockFocus]` and see at least which view might be involved. It likely has nothing to do with your `btnShowPriceSource` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same message while trying to display a modal window while clicking a button.

Problem solved the code showing the modal "outside" of the code called by the button.

In your case that would be:

```
- (IBAction)btnShowPriceSource:(id)sender {
    if (ps == nil){

        ps = [[PriceSource alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PriceSource"];

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [ps showWindow:nil];
    }
}
```

The code within the block should be executed right after whatever is locking the focus on the button release it.